# Actionscript: unable to assign JSON decoded object as dataProvider

Tags: actionscript-3, json, dataprovider

I am trying to use JSON decoded as a dataProvider, but no matter what I try I get errors such as the following:

```
Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert    
mx.collections::ArrayCollection@2a88ae01 to fl.data.DataProvider.
```

I am only returning a simple JSON object array of 3 elements with 3 properties each.

I am currently doing the following:

```
  var arr:Array = (JSON.decode(rawData) as Array);

  var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(arr);

  grid.dataProvider = dp;
```

**EDIT - MORE INFO**

If I change the last line of the above code to

```
      grid.dataProvider = new DataProvider(dp);
```

I get the following error

```
    TypeError: Error: Type Coercion failed: 
    cannot convert [object Object],[object Object] to Array or DataProvider.
```

Comment: Is this a modular application?  The error looks like one you'd see when you try to use a class outside of the domain into which it was imported.

Comment: @Ryan It is/will be, but at the moment all code is in a single .as file named the same as the .fla file that contains the DataGrid component

Comment: And you are sure that you're not violating and crossdomain rules? See here http://blog.aleksandarandreev.com/?tag=error-1034

Comment: What happens if you just assign the array directly to the dataProvider property on the grid?

Comment: @Ryan I have tried directly assigning and get the same error as above (first example).. If I debug I can see the data has been successfully recieved into the 'arr' variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What changing the last line to this?

```
grid.dataProvider = new DataProvider(arr);
```

Comment: I see the edit, but it looks like you are trying to cast the array collection dp to a DataProvider and not the array arr

Comment: Appologies.. I have tried what youy suggested.... and it works!! Typically the only thing I hadnt tried! Many Thanks Ryan